# Angular route not resolving from observable

Tags: angular

I'm trying to resolve a route in Angular and cannot get it to resolve. Whilst the resolver works when I return a value it does not continue to the intended route. My router is defined as follows...

```
{ 
    path: 'sortation', 
    component: SortationComponent,
    resolve: {
        cage: 'cageResolveService'
    }           
}
```

... which I call using a simple link

```
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm" routerLink="/sortation" routerLinkActive="menu-active">
            Sortation
        </a>
```

... and my cageResolveService reads

```
import { Injectable, Inject, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Cage } from '../_models/cage';

@Injectable()
export class CageResolveService implements Resolve<any> {

cage;

constructor(
    @Inject('cageService') private cageService,
    @Inject('appUtilityService') private appUtilityService,
    @Inject('flashService') private flashService
) {}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cage.unsubscribe();
}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {

    let criteria = {
        "limit": 3,
        "orderBy": "createdAt",
        "state": "PICKED"
    }

    // Subscribe to the observable
    this.cage = this.cageService.load( this.appUtilityService.encode( criteria ) )
    .subscribe();

    return this.cageService.cages$
    .map( cages => {

        if( cages && cages.length )
        {
            let c = cages.find( cage => cage.state === 'PICKED' );
            return c;
        }
        else
        {
            this.flashService.command.next({message: 'Error : No ready cages at this time', type: 'danger'});
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Can anybody please advise? If I remove the resolver the route works fine. It's a silly issue that is driving me nuts.

Comment: To me it doesn't look like your 2nd code block is related to your question. How and from where do you try to navigate to the `sortation` route?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. The 2nd code block is my resolver which returns an object or boolean false. I call the route via a simple button on a webpage. I have updated the question.

Comment: I see. So it's the resolver that is not resolving, not the route. There are similar errors when the router couldn't find a matching route. Hard from here to tell why it's not resolving. A first step would be to add some debug output to see what code path is executed and what values causes this code path.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody struggling the issue was caused by not closing the observable. I amended my code inside the resolver as follows:

cageResolverService

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'
...
... ...

resolve(): any {

    let criteria = {
        "limit": 1,
        "orderBy": "createdAt",
        "state": "PICKED"
    }

    // Subscribe to the observable
    this.cage = this.cageService.load( this.appUtilityService.encode( criteria ) )
    .subscribe();

    var self = this;

    return self.cageService.cages$
    .map( cages => {

        if( cages && cages.length )
        {
            return cages.find( cage => cage.state === 'PICKED' );
        }
        else
        {
            self.flashService.command.next({message: 'Error : No ready cages at this time', type: 'danger'});
            return false;
        }
    })
    .first();
}
```

NOTE: The addition of "first();" at the end of the method which closes the observable and allows the route to render.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [routerLink]="['sortation']  I think routerlink declaraion is mistake
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I discovered the issue and detailed it above.